# Docker container with Jmeter Jenkins stops after some time

Tags: docker, jenkins, jmeter

I am trying to integrate Jenkins and Jmeter inside the Docker. For this I am using official Jenkins docker file. My Job in Jenkins, starts the Jmeter's execution. All works fine. But after some time, the   jenkins server stops (and so the docker container). 
The docker logs only shows

```
"INFO: JVM is terminating. Shutting down Winstone".
```

Docker version - 17.04.0 CE,
Jmeter version - 3.1 and 
Jenkins - 2.46.1

Not sure what and why JVM is terminated. Need help.

Comment: What does docker log says? May be try increasing memory if it is short of memory.

Comment: @Rao,  2017-05-04T06:35:17.452637660Z
2017-05-04T06:45:47.585636304Z  May 04, 2017 6:45:47 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
2017-05-04T06:45:47.585654526Z  INFO: JVM is terminating. Shutting down Winstone

Comment: I dont think "memory" is the issue, as Jmeter execution is completed.